# What was wrong in my reply that my research guide changed his mind?

Tags: research-process, advisor, supervision

During my masters I spoke with my research guide and he seemed to be interested in taking me as a PhD student afterwards. I joined a job and want to start my PhD after a year.

My research guide mailed me recently asking if I am joining back as a PhD student, as he is getting a new project, and looking for someone capable like me. I was very happy getting a mail from my guide and with my gladness, probably I spoke too much. I told him that I am not completely happy with the work I am doing currently, so I will be happy to work on his project on my free time, but since I am getting salary from my current job, I can work on the project only when I get time out of my job. I also told him that I am appearing in the PhD entrance exam in 1-2 years.

After this he was silent for a week, then replied back that I mistook what he meant, he is looking for someone who can start PhD work and join later in the institute as a PhD student through examination. If I know any such person, I can let him know.

I am not able to understand what went wrong here. I replied that I am appearing in exam and interested to join back my institute, but since I am in a job I can't start PhD full time, but once I get recruited as a PhD student in the institute, I will start full time work. After that he didn't reply back.

He definitely was checking if I am joining PhD, otherwise he wouldn't have mailed me. He was also aware that I am joining a job. Then what went wrong in my answer that he changed his mind, I am unable to understand.

Can anyone point this out?

Also, any suggestion, how can I amend the situation now?

Comment: Do you and him speak the same language natively?

Comment: yes. We communicated in English.

Comment: Not sure what country this is, but it sounds like you just misunderstood, but somehow explained it to us quite clearly that he is looking for a PhD student now, but you aren't looking to be a PhD student now. Bryan's answer seems correct.

Comment: I'm unable to understand why you believe he changed his mind. He didn't. You declined his offer.

Comment: Not related, but if he often goes silent by your emails, are you sure it is a good idea to work with him at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A phone call is the only way to fix the situation.

Call him and clearly express that you are not going to drop your job before having confirmation of the PhD. Ask them if you can still apply for the position.

However, with the first mail they offered you the position and you rejected.
Instead of what you write, it would have been smart to ask if that mail was a concrete offer or an informal communication (sorry, I know that the horse has left the barn, keep in mind this for the future)

You must make very clear that you did not take the first email as an official offer.

Answer (score 12):

> I can work on the project only when I get time out of my job. I also told him that I am appearing in the PhD entrance exam in 1-2 years

Your advisor isn't looking for someone to work on the project in their free time and to maybe start a PhD after at least 1-2 years, they are looking for someone to work full-time on the project *now*.

Your response indicated you wouldn't be available to work on their timeline and stated your priority is your other job instead.

It maybe would have been kind for them to reach out and clarify this with you, to make clear that the position is only available to you if you can take it now. However, it's also reasonable that they look for another candidate since you've told them you're not available on the timeline they are looking for.

Comment: But isn't it normal? He was already aware I am going to join a job after my masters. How can I leave job without getting confirmation that I am getting a chance in my PhD?

Comment: So, does it mean, I can contact him again for some other project he might have, while I appear for the entrance exam for PhD?

Comment: @MadamCurie I'm not sure what's normal in your system where there is an "entrance exam" for a PhD. Maybe they assumed you would have already taken the exam if you were interested in a PhD. In any case, it doesn't sound like you said clearly "I will quit my job if I have a PhD position". You instead said you could only work in your free time because you have another job.

Comment: Yes, probably it was not clear in my first mail, but I clearly mentioned it in my second email. But no reply .. Any idea on how to amend this situation now?

Comment: @MadamCurie If you wrote it like you said here, I don't think it was clear. You could try again, but maybe it's not available anymore.